# Angular 2/4/5 - Bind UTC formatted date to datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I am very new to Angular and Angular Material.

For the dates my backend wants it to be in zonedDate Format.
(e.g.: 2018-04-11T02:12:04.455Z[UTC])

So I am getting value in the above format, which is not binding to mat-datepicker.

Here is html code:

```
<mat-form-field class="fx-cell-1" floatLabel="never">
    <input matInput name="myDate" [matDatepicker]="myDate" placeholder="Date of Expense"
    [(ngModel)]="myDate" #myDate="ngModel" [max]="maxDate" required >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #myDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

So here ngModel is not binding value to datepicker.

After some more observation, I realized that:

The date with value "**2018-04-11T02:12:04.455Z[UTC]**" is **binding** to the datepicker.

The date with value "**2018-04-02T14:00Z[UTC]**" is **not binding** to the datepicker.

Any suggestion???

Comment: if your date is a simple string, did you try to wrap it into a `new Date('myDate')` before using it in your datepicker?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it always gives an error saying "Invalid Date".

Comment: I tried both strings in `new Date()`, but both saying *Invalid Date*. After removing the `[UTC]` from the string, both would be correctly read as a date time instance in UTC time. So simply strip of the brackets part and everything should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you can convert this date with javascript function **toISOString()**.

or just by creating **new Date()** object.

*In my case date was converting into some wrong format and so was getting an error.*